# Renaming Realm DB file

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I have an old project with realm db, i am updating that to the newer realm version. i checked there was a funny name given to realm file. 
I want to change that name but haven't found any documentation about that.
Has any done this before ?

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("funnyName.realm")
                .schemaVersion(5)
                .migration(new RealmMigrationScript())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can copy your old realm into a new realm (with your updated name) file
2. Perform Data migration for all old names
3. Once the new realm is created, set is as default instance.